# Glitched display on remote desktop

Tags: display, remote-desktop

I wanted to remote to my work station, but on connecting I get a glitched screen. Everything else works fine, I can open programs ect.

The same glitch is occurring if I from the computer without remote desktop want to use Snipping tool or another screen capturing tool.

All my AMD FirePro video drivers are up to date. It's a AMD FirePro W7100 GPU.

[How A Remote desktop session looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D02NS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

open your remote desktop connect window > in the bottom left click "show options" > "Display" tab > make sure the colors profile is set to "Highest Quality (32 bit)". Then try out the connection.

Comment: I did this, and it's set to 32 bit. No luck.